SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory Laravel Ubuntu
I had a problem when I switched from Windows to Linux and I wanted to migrate the database gave me this error.
xampp is running good and the database is created in phpmyadmin.
I try to clear the cache with php artisan cache:clear,
and try to to check pdo_mysql if is like this ;extension=pdo_mysql
and I try to change localhost to 127.0.0.1 without success.

do php artisan migrate:install

What's the version of Laravel?

This question is similar to: PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There are a lot of such issues within stackoverflow related to your question. Please check them out.
